# javascript push then sort array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, push

I've created an array called 'shopping', a shopping list, that is already populated with some items.

I have created a prompt for users to add a new item to the shopping list.

I used the push method to add the user's new item to the 'shopping' array. Then I used the sort method to sort the whole list alphabetically. Then I displayed the updated and sorted shopping list.

The problem:  The output is the original 'shopping' array sorted alphabetically with the new item at the top of the list, out of alphabetical order.  For example if the user adds 'beans' to the list the list is displayed as:

Shopping List: 
Beans
apples
bacon
ham
pears
tuna

How do I get the updated shopping list to display properly alphabetically?

```js
var shopping = new Array("apples","pears","bacon","tuna","ham");
var newItem = prompt("Add a new item to your shopping list ","");
shopping.push(newItem);// adds users new item to the shopping list
shopping.sort();// sorts array alphabetically
document.write("Shopping List: <br/>");
for(i=0;i<shopping.length;i++){
  document.write(shopping[i] + "<br/>");
}
```

Comment: The problem is that *Beans* (and only Beans) starts with a capital letter, not that it was pushed onto the array.

Comment: You're right. That worked. Thanks Quentin.  (I did search for push and sort in the database as I didn't realise the problem was case-sensitivity so the solutions didn't appear in my search)